# High Voltage & Current Circuit From Small Power Source

Tags: circuit-design, high-voltage, high-current

Is there any way that I can create a high voltage and current generator circuit from low power source such as lead acid battery? eg; 12V to 10 kV and 1A

Most high voltage generator such as ZVS or Cockroft-Walton do provide a large amount of voltage but small in current.Do I need to charge a large capacitor to make large peak currents?

Comment: Are you asking for continuous operation or pulsed? If pulsed, what pulse width and what frequency?

Comment: So your question is:  How do I get 1A from 12V to 10kV from a battery?

Comment: Is period of 2 second consider as continuous? If yes than it is continuous.

Comment: You can't generate power, you can only convert it. You can't get out more power than you put in.

Comment: StainlessSteelRat yes you are right.

Comment: DerStrom8 I do agree with that, so you can get either high voltage or current conversion from the source right?

Comment: You can get anything you want, as long as P_out <= P_in.

Comment: @DerStrom8 perhaps you are confusing power with energy?

Comment: You set a very unrealistic scenario. 10 kV at 1 A is 10 kW. 10 kW at 12 V is about 800 A. Most LA batteries (car starter size) can only sustain this type of power rating for a few minutes at best.     The best you are likely to do is to store the 10 kV in a capacitor bank and get a very small pulse at high power.

Comment: Thanks Jack, now I start to see the relation. So from my understanding it is only possible if we do in a short burst of high voltage and current like a Marx or Impulsed generator right?

Comment: @SredniVashtar No I am not confusing power with energy. Energy is simply power over a period of time, so the same rule that applies for power applies for energy, and that is that you can't create it. You can only convert it.

Comment: @DerStrom8 And you are wrong. Because that "period of time" need not be the same for the "in" and "out".

Comment: @SredniVashtar I see your point, I suppose it would be more accurate to say that Pavg(in) = Pavg(out)

Comment: No, I don't think that would be generally valid either, since you can make the two time periods arbitrarily different and even the discharge profile can be changed.

Comment: @JackCreasey - Plus, at these current levels the battery output will be a good deal less than the nominal 12 volts. 10 kW is about 13 horsepower, and you're not getting that from a car battery.

Answer (score 2):

You want a 10kV source that can supply 1A. We know P=VI, so that's a 10kW supply.

Now look at your little 12V lead-acid. Ignoring efficiency losses, that battery must supply all 10kW of power. Since the battery's voltage is (nearly) constant at 12V, then it must supply **833A** of current.

Do you think it's realistic your lead-acid battery can supply 833A?

Comment: Time. You forgot about time.

Comment: True, but I answered based on assumptions from the OPs comments where he mentioned 2sec on times.

Comment: Your idea that the battery should be providing 833 amps is wrong. You could perhaps spend hours and drain all the battery capacity (at far far less than 800 amps, I'd say within battery specs) and then release all the energy drained in two seconds. The idea that Pout should be <=Pin is not generally valid. (It is for sinusoidal steady state circuits, though)

Comment: I think your assessment that my answer is wrong is a little harsh. Yes, I agree that there are alternative ways to achieve the end result, but within the context of what the OP is asking, I believe my answer addresses his question. Since it's unlikely the OP is asking for a method that will require hours of charge time, along with a large and potentially dangerous charge bank, I think it is safe to omit that kind of solution from the answer.

Comment: The wrong part is assuming that  the battery should provide the maximum amperage continuously. I said hours to make an extreme example - it could be minutes (I did not compute anything, but I guess a car battery can supply tens of amps for a few minutes without big problems - that should be enough to make up for the hundreds of amps required in a few seconds). As for the "potentially dangerous" charge banks, I guess it's up to the users decide. And I said userS in the plural because some other user might be willing to take the risk. The Electroboom guy, for example.

Comment: Again, within the context of the question asked by the OP, the level of understanding of electronics design the OP appears to be demonstrating, and various other assumptions, I believe my answer provides him with the information he was seeking. My answer is not wrong. If you want to provide an answer that works under different assumptions, please feel free.

Comment: Since you restated your previous comment, my answer to you is to reread my previous comment. Oh, and the Electroboom guy is this guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0utNemFsl8

Comment: My, you're an obstinate one. I hope you have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Cranking Amps is defined at 7.5V which is a drop from 12.5V fully charged.

Thus to generate 10kW for crank duration you need 1333 Amps which would be about a 50kg truck battery. and a DC converter worth about $5k

nice try but no good